# What does this configure 'heartbeat_interval' means in RabbitMQ？

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

There are 2 items in RabbitMQ Server configures about heartbeat:

```
rabbitmq-diagnostics environment |grep  -i heartbeat
      {heartbeat_interval,100},
      {heartbeat,60},
```

I know that `heartbeat` item is the value representing the heartbeat timeout suggested by the server during connection parameter negotiation.

But what does it mean by `heartbeat_interval`? Is it about cluster?

Comment: It is client side interval regulating frequency of heartbeats, server has no support for this parameter. Set it very high - you effectively disable heartbeat, Set it very low - you get more responsive client, but sometime can exhaust server connection pool. Usually you leave it be because it fallbacks to heartbeat/2 interval. After 2 failed tries rabbitmq client become disconnected on client side. On server it just becomes disconnected on heartbeat timeout. The reason it exists to make heartbeat timeout very low and not to spam server with heartbeats. Ie heartbeat = 5 sec, interval = 60 sec.

Comment: Is there any online material for  this？

Comment: Please check [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html)

Comment: I donot think so. it is  the client not the Server.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html#heartbeats-interval) the `heartbeat_interval` value is more commonly referred to as Heartbeat Frames. If I'm interpreting the documentation correctly, then the interval is how often the client sends heartbeats. It also goes on to say any traffic is considered a heartbeat frame, and RabbitMQ can be configured to send frames dependent on whether or not there's traffic.